# Python scripting inside PowerBI

Tags: python, powerbi-desktop

I am reproducing a simple example from here to run Python into Power BI desktop :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-scripts

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'],dtype=float) 
print (df)
```

I do not know where to begin to solve this error:

```
Details: "ADO.NET: Python script error.
<pi>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 2, in <module>
    import os, pandas, matplotlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 159, in _check_versions
    from . import ft2font
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ft2font: The specified module could not be found.
</pi>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works :

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install --upgrade matplotlib

pip uninstall pandas
pip install --upgrade pandas

pip uninstall pillow
pip install --upgrade pillow
```